# Run chrome webpage as desktop application

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, ubuntu-gnome

I am looking to run a couple web pages as desktop applications in Gnome shell. These are the requirements:

1. It must run with Google Chrome.
2. It must be available as a separate app icon when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I have looked at a program called Webby, but it does not seem to use Google Chrome as the underlying browser. So far I created my .desktop file and have been able to get the application and icon to show in the launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gmail
Exec=google-chrome-stable --app=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
Icon=gmail-icon
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Office;
```

This works and allows me to launch the application in a separate window, however, when I press Alt+Tab everything is still combined under the google chrome icon. I have tried creating a symlink as well for the exec path, this didn't work either. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This might not be what you're looking for. But if you want to pin a Google Chrome website to the desktop as a web application you can do the following:

- Click the 3 dots on the top-right corner
- Click `More tools`
- Click `Create shortcut...`
- Select the `Open as window` checkbox

Hope I helped!

**Chrome > Version 70**

Update for new versions of Chrome, where no `Open as window` checkbox appears:

- Click the 3 dots on the top-right corner
- Click `More tools`
- Click `Create shortcut...`
- Click `Create`
- Navigate to `chrome://apps`
- Right-click on the new app
- Click `Open as window`

Comment: And how do I remove this?

Comment: @Gocht you should be able to see apps created this way and remove them from chrome://apps/

Comment: The 'Open as window' does not show anymore (ubuntu 18.04). How can I force it?

Comment: @ronenmiller Regarding your edit suggestion, it would be better to post a separate answer, and you can link to this answer if it helps.

Comment: With chrome 72 In order to make it a full fledged app with separate icons and distinct entry in alt+tab, I had to go to chrome://apps right click on the app and choose 'create shortcuts'

Comment: Some idea about how to do this via command line, I mean in a non-interactive way?

Comment: Some idea for how to do this via command line?

Comment: Thanks so much, been looking to do this for a while!

Comment: not working in Ubuntu 20.04 and latest Chrome. The launcher icon is merged together. Can you update the answer?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking the 3 dots in the upper-right corner of Chromium or google-chrome, click More Tools > Create Shortcut... > Create

Which also creates a desktop shortcut but it won't work until this trick is done.

Here I show you how to make Instagram a desktop app.

We can see this code after creating a shortcut from chromium and opening it in a text editor

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Instagram1
Exec=/snap/chromium/2033/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome "--profile-directory=Profile 1" --app-id=maonlnecdeecdljpahhnnlmhbalehlm
Icon=chrome-maonlnecdeecdljpahhnnlmhbmalehlm-Profile_1
StartupWMClass=crx_maonlnecdeecdljpahhnnlmhbmalehlm
```

Just change

`/snap/chromium/2033/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome`
or

`/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

to `chromium`, `google-chrome`, or `google-chrome -incognito`

If you create multiple profiles in Google Chrome, you can write like this

`google-chrome --profile-directory='Default'` or

`google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile 1" -incognito`

For example

```
Exec=/snap/chromium/2033/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome "--profile-directory=Profile 1" --app-id=maonlnecdeecdljpahhnnlmhbalehlm
```

will be

```
Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile 1" -incognito --password-store=basic --app-id=maonlnecdeecdljpahhnnlmhbalehlm
```

I used --password-store=basic to ignore keyring password.

For icon, I downloaded the Instagram app icon from online and showed the location like this and it worked immediately

```
Icon=/home/virus-attack/Icon/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.ico
```

Now you can pin this shortcut to your panel too