How to create a custom Firefox desktop entry which correctly maps to the instance it launches?
Purpose
My intention is to create a firefox icon pinned to the dock that launches firefox in a personal profiles and is also indicated with a dot under the icon that launched it. (currently firefox launches the personal profile but the indicator still appears under the original firefox desktop entry)
What I Tried
I created a custom desktop entry for firefox and placed it in ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_custom.desktop
The entry is a copy of the desktop entry in /snap/firefox/current/firefox.desktop with the following modification:

Exec is changed to firefox --no-remote -P "Personal" --name FirefoxPersonal
Added StartupWMClass=FirefoxPersonal
Icon points to an alternative image (firefox icon edited with Gimp to be slightly different)

What I See
By following different questions and specs I expected to have the indicator (the little dot next the icon) to be on my new icon. But instead it appears on the original firefox.
When I check the wm_class for the window (with alt+f2 and typing lg), I see it's set to FirefoxPersonal, and yet it's not mapped correctly to the desktop icon that I set with StartupWMClass=FirefoxPersonal.
My Question(s)

What to change in my desktop entry to have it indicated separately on the desktop entry?
I also want to understand how are desktop entries get associated to the process/window they run? What's the process that happens behind the scenes when a process starts that eventually ends up with a dot indicator next to app icon of a specific desktop entry?


see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1492754/1698042

Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for. I want to create a desktop entry by myself and I want to understand how desktop entries are associated with a process/window in the window manager. I'll edit my question to reflect that

Also, I just installed such a shortcut in chrome and when I open it I see the indicator on the chromium app icon instead of the shortcut I launched it from. Possibly this behavior is broken in Ubuntu 24.04?

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/811657/1698042

In addition to the option --name FirefoxPersonal, also add the option --class FirefoxPersonal to the Exec= line.

Already tried it. doesn't work :(
Exec=/snap/bin/firefox --name=firefox-custom --class=firefox-custom %u

That is because firefox is already running. Fr it to work in combination with Firefox as default browser, you will need to have the new instance use a different profile.
